# How to notify a DataGrid about re-ordering of elements within the original list?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say we have a list of cars: `List<string> cars` and our GUI holds a `DataGrid` with `ItemsSource` set to `new ObservableCollection<string>(cars)`.

**Example**:

```
List<string> cars = new List<string>() { "Ford", "BMW" };
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<string>(cars);
```

So far so good. Now we add a Button to our GUI which moves down the first car in the list one place down inside our model `List<Car> cars`. I.e. re-orders the list `cars`.

**Example**: After one click we have: `cars = {"BMW", "Ford"}"`.

But the DataGrid does not change, because it just listens to `INotifyPropertyChanged` of the elements within the list, but does not listen to re-order changes about the original list `cars` itself.

**Question:** How to tell the `DataGrid` to listen for events about the original list itself?

Comment: This is done with the underlying ListCollectionView.  Do you need an indicative snippet?

Comment: @GayotFow Sure, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do this from a View Model (or code-behind) is the ListCollectionView.  Here is a sample snippet....

```
ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
List<Person> MyList = new List<Person>(); 
public ViewModel()
{
    Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(MyList);
    ListCollectionView listCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Persons) as ListCollectionView;
    if (listCollectionView != null)
    {
        listCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
        listCollectionView.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
    }
}
```

The ListCollectionView is generated by the binding engine when the source is a collection that inherits from IList.  You access it as demonstrated and then populate its sort descriptions (from major to minor).

Add and remove the sort descriptions whenever you want your grid sorted in a different way.  You can also sort in real-time by setting the appropriate property on the ListCollectionView.

Comment: Thanks, but do re-order changes in the original list notify the  ListCollectionView to be re-ordered?

Comment: no, if you want to change the order (e.g., from ascending to descending), it needs to go through the ListCollectionView.  Use listCollectionView.IsLiveSorting = true; to make additions to the collection live.